# Ошибка - метод не объявлен в определении обобщенного типа

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Я пытаюсь сгенерировать динамически следующую обобщенную функцию:

```
MyList<T> CreateList<T>(T arg) => new MyList<T>(){arg};
```

Ниже приведена программа с небольшими модификациями из документации(оригинальная программа тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-define-a-generic-method-with-reflection-emit). Ключевой момент для меня это вызов метода `Add`, реализованного в классе `List`. Его я получаю посредством метода `TypeBuilder.GetMethod`:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
}
public static void Main()
{
    var asmName = new AssemblyName("DemoMethodBuilder1");
    var demoAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);

    var demoModule = demoAssembly.DefineDynamicModule(asmName.Name, asmName.Name + ".dll");
    var demoType = demoModule.DefineType("DemoType", TypeAttributes.Public);

    var create_list_method = demoType.DefineMethod("CreateList", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static);

    var TInput = create_list_method.DefineGenericParameters(new string[] { "TInput" })[0];
    var t_list_type = typeof(MyList<>).MakeGenericType(TInput);

    create_list_method.SetParameters(new Type[] { TInput });
    create_list_method.SetReturnType(t_list_type);

    var ilgen = create_list_method.GetILGenerator();

    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, TypeBuilder.GetConstructor(t_list_type, typeof(MyList<>).GetConstructors()[0]));
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, TypeBuilder.GetMethod(t_list_type, typeof(MyList<>).GetMethod("Add")));
    ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    demoType.CreateType();
    demoAssembly.Save(asmName.Name + ".dll");
}
```

Но в процессе выполнения программа падает в строчке`ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, TypeBuilder.GetMethod(t_list_type, typeof(MyList<>).GetMethod("Add")));` c сообщением:

> The specified method cannot be dynamic or global and must be declared on a generic type definition

Я не могу понять, почему такой код падает в рантайме? Потому что я как понял, он должен работать, для я этого я специально использовал статический метод `TypeBuilder.GetMethod`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что этот метод относится к типу `List<T>`, а не `MyList<T>`.

Когда вы ищите его в классе `MyList<>` (определение обобщенного типа), он оказывается найден в классе `List<T>` (инстанс обобщенного типа!). Чтобы такого не происходило - нужно искать метод в том классе где он и объявлен (тем более что такая проверка в `TypeBuilder.GetMethod` тоже есть, только до нее не доходит):

```
TypeBuilder.GetMethod(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(TInput), typeof(List<>).GetMethod("Add"))
```

Comment: Этот вариант не пройдет я так уже пробовал. упадет по другому исключению (в исходниках .net дальше проверка такая `if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != method.DeclaringType)`)

Comment: @LmTinyToon да ну? А почему у меня не падает?

Comment: стоп, уже увидел. Вы еще и изменили тип в выражении `typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(TInput)`, это тогда вообще другой код (сейчас проверю код)

Comment: действительно, ваш код работает. Но я не могу понять, как такое возможно? мне ведь нужен метод у UFXList, почему нам нужно создавать обощенный тип у List? Можете пожалуйста чуть подробнее обьяснить?

Comment: @LmTinyToon в вашем классе MyList нужного метода **нет**, он находится в базовом классе. Просто обычно такие ситуации разруливает компилятор, и это незаметно...